# How to call trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() method in apache poi 3.17

Tags: java, apache-poi

I cannot call trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() method and I need to know what is the library that includes the trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() method.
I have imported poi-3.17, poi-ooxml-3.17, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17 and poi-scratchpad-3.17 libraries to the project already.

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
...
...
sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing(); //
sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
```

[image: example image]

Comment: It is [SXSSFSheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing--) and you have only the Interface `Sheet`. So it would must be `((SXSSFSheet)sheet).trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();`. But your code should fail on `Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);` on runtime since `new SXSSFWorkbook()` creates a empty workbook without sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

The required method is only part of SXSSFSheet and not a method of Sheet interface.

Check the 
[Apidoc reference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing--)

Comment: Hello I have same problem and I am using poi 3.15 . trying to solved with thge requested solution doen not solve it . Any other suggestions please ??

Comment: Please provide details like source code or describe what exactly the same problem is, that you are facing. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is solving .. it was related to the project jar problem . but adding :((SXSSFSheet)sheet).trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

((SXSSFSheet)sheet).trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() solve the issue :)